# how to add javascript inside Joomla Module

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla

I wana to add a php, javascript and html code inside the a joomla Module or article. Javascript does not work normaly .
i have done in the way of

```
 <?php 
 include 'file.php';
 <?
```

should i rewrite to code in certain way ? or there is some thing in Joomla must be done. 
For example iam trying to use jquery with bootstrap .

please help me

thank you

Comment: It might be better to update your original question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/42682909/1983389 rather than continuing to ask related questions here and at http://stackoverflow.com/q/42702032/1983389

Answer (score 0):

for Java script,

```
$url = "Your script url";
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript($url);
```

also refer https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page